# asp.net core, angular 2, PrimeNG

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, webpack, primeng, server-side-rendering

I use [aspnetcore-spa template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnetcore-spa) as starting point to create admin panel. 
Next I add [PrimeNG](http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup) library to use it's components.

Unfortunately, when I import i.e. ButtonModule to app.module.ts and refresh, I get an error 'Event is undefined'. I can't figure out what is the reason for several days, so can anyone help me?

**UPDATE**

- So first of all I generate the stub with `yo aspnetcore-spa`
- Next `npm install font-awesome primeng --save`
- Then I add font-awesome and PrimeNG css files to `webpack.config.vendor.js`

  ```
   vendor: [
      '@angular/common',
      '@angular/compiler',
      '@angular/core',
      '@angular/http',
      '@angular/platform-browser',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
      '@angular/router',
      '@angular/platform-server',
      'angular2-universal',
      'angular2-universal-polyfills',
      'bootstrap',
      'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
      'es6-shim',
      'es6-promise',
      'event-source-polyfill',
      'jquery',
      'zone.js',            
      'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
      'primeng/resources/themes/sunny/theme.css',
      'primeng/resources/primeng.css'
  ]
  ```
- Rebuild vendor dependencies `webpack --config webpack.config.vendor.js`
- Then I import ButtonModule to app.module.ts

Now if I start the app I'll get exception
[image: Error page: ReferenceError: Event is not defined]

Exception point to this fragment of code

```
 __decorate([
    core_1.HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event']), 
    __metadata('design:type', Function), 
    __metadata('design:paramtypes', [Event]), 
    __metadata('design:returntype', void 0)
```

**UPDATE 2**

I've figured out that problem was in server-side rendering, so I removed it. It works for me, but it is still interesting how to solve this without turning of server-side rendering.

Comment: Could you describe the steps you take a bit more? Using angular-cli it works fine for me.

Comment: @KlasMellbourn I updated post with all steps that I've made.

Comment: in your tsconfig, have you disabled `lib.d.ts`?

Comment: Hey were you able to fix it without turning off server side pre-rendering?

Comment: The same problem, still no luck without removing asp-prerender-module

Comment: @Evgeny, it's not a problem of Asp.NET Core, just Primeng does not support server side rendering.

Answer (score 3):

```html
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>

<app>Loading...</app>
```

you need to disable the pre render from the server side, from index.cshtml.

change

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

to

```
<app>Loading...</app>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

*There are limitations with server-side rendering. Notably, your application code can’t just assume it always runs in a browser. If you try to reference the browser’s DOM directly, you’ll get an error like window is undefined when it runs server-side. Fortunately that’s rarely a problem, because in a well-architected Angular app (or React, etc.), the framework really doesn’t want you to mess with the DOM directly anyway, so you shouldn’t be assuming browser primitives regardless of server-side rendering.*

Lookimng at the javascript file in primeng, some control is manipulating the DOM tree

I am using the same template as you, if you do the following, you can keep the

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

The answer is, instead of doing

```
import { AccordionModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

do

```
import { AccordionModule } from 'primeng/components/accordion/accordion';
import { BlockUIModule } from 'primeng/components/blockui/blockui';
```

AccordionModule is dependent on BlockUI if you open accordion.d.ts, so we have to import it as well

It works for me without removing the prerendering

then go to web.config.vendor.js, modify

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
        { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css']) }
    ]
},
```

to

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?|$)/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' },
        { test: /\.css(\?|$)/, loader: extractCSS.extract(['css']) },
        { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url', query: { limit: 25000 } }
    ]
},
```

also in web.config.vendor.js, vendor section, add

```
'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'primeng/resources/primeng.min.css',
        'primeng/resources/themes/bootstrap/theme.css',
```

then open visual studio command prompt, and navigate to the solution path

```
   webpack --config web.config.vendor.js
```

However, there are some controls which will still throw an error
In this case, no choice but to modify the js file

Answer (score 2):

I found out a solution and got it working on one my pet project.

Just follow these steps (I skip the installation since you've already done that):

**1-** Add the loader for `gif` files since they are required in related `css` files:

```
loaders: [
    ...
    { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url', query: { limit: 25000 } }
]
```

**2-** Add the styles to your `webpack.config.vendor.js`:

```
vendor: [
   ...
   'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css',
   'primeng/resources/themes/lightness/theme.css',
   'primeng/resources/primeng.css'
]
```

**3-** add the modules you want to top of the `app.module.ts`:

```
import { AccordionModule } from 'primeng/components/accordion/accordion';
import { BlockUIModule } from 'primeng/components/blockui/blockui';
```

**4-** Add it to your `imports` as well:

```
imports: [
   UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
   RouterModule.forRoot([
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
        { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
        { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
        { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
    ]),
    AccordionModule
]
```

And voila...

You can find the working code [here](https://github.com/YAdelMehraban/AspnetcoreAngular2PrimeNg).