# Angular2 adding PrimeNG to my solution tag not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have been doing angular for three days now and finally got a login page dashboard up and running with a web api solution and works great, so my following issue is most probably my stupidity please bear with me.

I am having trouble loading in PrimeNG DataTableModule to work on my components, i search similar post regarding my error and what i gathered is that there can be two reasons for the following error: Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dataTable'.

There can be two reasons:
1) The module is not defined in the app.module.ts.
2) or property does not exists.

**My first question**: Why do my solution have my app.module.ts spitted up into three ts files [app.module.client.ts, app.module.server.ts and a app.module.shared.ts] ?

**My Second Question** When adding the DataTableModule to the app.module.client.ts i get this error: Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dataTable'. 
When adding the DataTableModule to the shared or server module file i get: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: Event is not defined 
what am i doing wrong?

Here is my code:
app.module.client.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';
import { AuthManager } from './auth/auth.manager';
import { UserIdentity } from './auth/user.identity';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';

import { DataTableModule, SharedModule } from 'primeng/primeng';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        DataTableModule,
        SharedModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports,
    ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'ORIGIN_URL', useValue: location.origin },
        AuthManager,
        UserIdentity,
        UserService
    ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

app.module.server.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { sharedConfig } from './app.module.shared';
import { AuthManager } from './auth/auth.manager';
import { UserIdentity } from './auth/user.identity';
import { UserService } from './services/user.service';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: sharedConfig.bootstrap,
    declarations: sharedConfig.declarations,
    imports: [
        ServerModule,
        FormsModule,
        ...sharedConfig.imports
    ],
    providers: [ AuthManager,
        UserIdentity,
        UserService]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

app.module.shared.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router'; 
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboad/dashboad.component';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component';
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './components/admin/admin.component';
import { SettingComponent } from './components/admin/settings/setting.component';
import { UserComponent } from './components/admin/users/user.component';

import { AuthManager } from './auth/auth.manager';

export const sharedConfig: NgModule = {
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        DashboardComponent,
        AdminComponent,
        UserComponent,
        SettingComponent,
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        HomeComponent, 
    ],
    imports: [
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            {
                path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, children: [
                    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthManager] },
                    { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent, canActivate: [AuthManager], children: [
                        { path: 'users', component: UserComponent, canActivate: [AuthManager] },
                        { path: 'settings', component: SettingComponent, canActivate: [AuthManager] },   
                        ]},
                    { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent, canActivate: [AuthManager] },
                ]
            },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ]),
    ]
};
```

Page where i am trying to implement the datagrid
user.component.html

```
<p-dataTable [value]="users">
    <p-column field="Email" header="Email"></p-column>
    <p-column field="Name" header="Name"></p-column>
    <p-column field="Surname" header="Surname"></p-column>
    <p-column field="Cellphone" header="Cellphone"></p-column>
    <p-column field="Telephone" header="Telephone"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

user.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService, UserViewModel } from '../../../services/user.service';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { DataTableModule, SharedModule } from 'primeng/primeng';


@Component({
    selector: 'user',
    templateUrl: './user.component.html'
})

export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

    users: UserViewModel[];

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(users => {
           this.users = users;
       });
    }
}
```

Error Message on with Module defined in the app.module.client.ts

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: Template
>   parse errors:  Can't bind to 'value' since it isn't a known property
>   of 'p-dataTable'.
>    1. If 'p-dataTable' is an Angular component and it has 'value' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
>    2. If 'p-dataTable' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>   to suppress this message.

Error Message on with Module defined in either the app.module.server.ts or app.module.shared.ts

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed
>   because of error: ReferenceError: Event is not defined
>   main-server.js:50676:38)

Comment: you are not importing the modules correctly. create a plunker to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was the server side prerendering not finding the dependencies of the toolset so the solution was to change the import modules section in the app.module.shared.ts from just using:

```
import { DataTableModule, SharedModule } from 'primeng/primeng';
```

to

```
import { DataTableModule } from 'primeng/components/datatable/datatable';
import { BlockUIModule } from 'primeng/components/blockui/blockui';
```

so now the toolset has a fullpath on the server side as well and i can still use prerendering on the server.

Credit goes to this post: [asp.net core, angular 2, PrimeNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40432428/asp-net-core-angular-2-primeng)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding DataTableModule and SharedModule imports into the sharedConfig NgModule?

I'm not familiar with the three split app.module files so I can't comment on that.

And this is an aside, but as PrimeNG says, if you use an import statement like this:

```
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

Then it imports all of the components which is probably not what you want. See their comment on that here:
https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

Comment: Yes I have tried that route as well as soon as I include it in the shared or the server app.module files I get the event not defined error it seems like the pages want to render on the server as well, when I remove the asp-prerender-module tag in the index.html it works 100%.

Comment: Any ideas how to make it work on server side rendering as well ? seems like it can't find the dependencies it is looking for, or any benefit to use the server-side prerendering?